# Extend and merge two arrays (that contain objects) in JS

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

So I have array A:

```
   var arrA = [{
      name: 'twitter',
      location: 0,
      hidden: false,
      href: "https://twitter.com/i/connect"
    }, {
      name: 'medium',
      location: 1,
      hidden: false,
      href: "https://medium.com/me/activity"
    }
  ];
```

And array B:

```
var arrB = [{
      name: 'twitter',
      location: 1,
      hidden: false
    }, {
      name: 'medium',
      location: 0,
      hidden: false
    }
  ];
```

How can I end up with an array that looks like this:

```
var newArr = [{
      name: 'twitter',
      location: 1,
      hidden: false,
      href: "https://twitter.com/i/connect"
    }, {
      name: 'medium',
      location: 0,
      hidden: false,
      href: "https://medium.com/me/activity"
    }
  ];
```

So, two things here, 1. the `location` values have been taken from `arrB`, not `arrA`, 2. that `newArr`'s objects now contain `href` keys, taken from `arrA`.

So values I need from the second array, but new keys are maintained from the first array.

Can I do this with an underscore.js function (I'm using _.extend right now, but it doesn't maintain the key from `arrA` if it's new)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether underscore has a function to merge the arrays like this, but you can write a function as given below to merge the arrays conditionally

```
Array.prototype.conditionalMerge = function(arr, props){

    var merged = [];

    for(var i=0; i<this.length;i++){
        var item = {};
        for(var attr in this[i]){
            item[attr] = (props[attr])?arr[i][attr]:this[i][attr];
        }
        merged.push(item);
    }

    return  merged;
}

arrA.conditionalMerge(arrB, {location:true})
```

Comment: This assumes that the objects in a and b are the same in number and order. It will also fail to copy over any additional properties in b, if there are such.

Answer (score 1):

You can join two arrays and select proper attributes with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) library:

```
var res1 = alasql('SELECT arrA.name, arrB.location, arrA.href, arrB.hidden \
            FROM ? arrA JOIN ? arrB USING name', [arrA,arrB]);
```

Or Underscore _.extend version of this:

```
alasql.fn.extend = _.extend.bind(_);
var res2 = alasql('SELECT COLUMN extend(arrA._, arrB._) 
                   FROM ? arrA JOIN ? arrB USING name', [arrA,arrB]);
```

Try these examples [at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/b7ofozjr/2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArr=[];
$.each(arrA, function(index, value) {
$.extend(value, arrB[index]);
newArr[index]=value
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QZzZM/

Comment: It's tagged with underscorejs, not jquery :)

Comment: I'll still take the answer!

Comment: This answer assumes that the the number of objects in a and b are the same and that they are in the same order, which might or might not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can "map" entries in `arrA` into themselves merged with the corresponding entries in `arrB`. In Underscore:

```
_.map(arrA, function(a) {
    return _.extend(a, _.find(arrB, function(b) {
        return a.name === b.name;
    }));
});
```

This solution has the charateristics that:

1. The objects may be appear in any order in the two arrays; they are matched up by name.
2. Any extra properties in the objects in array b will be copied over.

#### In native JS

```
arrA.map(function(a) {
    return Object.assign(a, arrB.find(function(b) {
        return a.name === b.name; 
    }));
});
```

`Object.assign` and [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), if not available, can be polyfilled. For example, here's a version of `find`:

```
Array.prototype.find = function(callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++ ) {
        if (callback(this[i], i, this)) return this[i];
    }
 });
```

Comment: what if there are extra objects in array B